# Turn based multiplayer match start error

Tags: android, google-play-games, google-play-developer-api

I am adding a turn based multiplayer game into my app. In the [google developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer)
the code displays an error message when the status IS success.

```
    public class MatchInitiatedCallback implements
        ResultCallback {

    @Override
    public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.InitiateMatchResult result) {
        // Check if the status code is not success.
        Status status = result.getStatus();
        if (status.isSuccess()) {
            showError(status.getStatusCode());
            return;
        }

        TurnBasedMatch match = result.getMatch();

        // If this player is not the first player in this match, continue.
        if (match.getData() != null) {
            showTurnUI(match);
            return;
        }

        // Otherwise, this is the first player. Initialize the game state.
        initGame(match);

        // Let the player take the first turn
        showTurnUI(match);
    }
}
```

Is that a mistake in the documentation or am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: Maybe they forgot a ! Why not asking them? There is a send feeback button on this page.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing just wondering if someone already knows the answer to it. Thanks anyway!